# R rename columns in many CSVs

Tags: r, loops, csv, rename, batch-rename

I have 200 csvs with the same two columns (date and level). However, the columns don't currently have names. They all need to have the same column names for a package I'm using in R. Is there a way to loop through all of the CSVs and give them all column names (the same column names, date and level)? I am new to R and don't have much experience writing loops.

For example, currently the data in each CSV looks like this:

```
09/21/1299 | 23
09/22/1999 | 25
09/23/1999 | 25
```

but I'd like it to look like this:

```
date       | level
09/21/1299 | 23
09/22/1999 | 25
09/23/1999 | 25
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `list.files(path = "./", pattern = "*.csv))` to get names of all csv files
2. Create a loop where you:

   - read in each file
   - assign column names to the data frame or matrix
   - write to a new file (or overwrite the original)

Answer (score 0):

In following code please change `wanted_colnames` which you wanted to assign to all columns. This code (with fixes if required) should read all csv inside folder `files_folder` (change it to give full path). At last you can `rbind_fill`/`rbindlist` on `dfs` to get full dataframe.

```
wanted_colnames <- c('var1', 'var2', 'var3')
files_folder <- '/files/folder/path'

docs <- list.files(files_folder)
dfs <- list()
for(doc in docs) {
   full_path <- file.path(files_folder, doc)
   dfs[doc] <- read.csv(full_path)
   names(dfs[doc]) <- wanted_colnames
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access all files in a folder you can use `list.files`, then you can read each of them with `read.csv` and lastly you should write them to new files with `write.csv`.

Overall you will have a code similar to following:

```
files <- list.files("path/to/directory/")
sapply(files, function(file){
                      x <- read.csv(file)
                      colnames(x) <- c("Col1", "Col2")
                      write.csv(paste0("new_", file),x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you do not simply want to read the files, but actually modify the files such that they contain column headers.

In order for the following code to work, you need to define two variables: `path` should point to the folder, where the original files are stored. `out_path` should be the path to a folder, where the modified files should be stored. If the folder `out_path` does not exist, it will be created.

This piece of code reads all the csv files in `path`, adds the headers and writes the modified files to the folder `out_path`:

```
# create the output folder
# showWarnings = FALSE ensures that the function does not complain,
# even if the folder already exists
dir.create(out_path, showWarnings = FALSE)

# get the names of the input files with their full path
files <- list.files(path, "\\.csv", full.name = TRUE)

# loop through all the input files
for (file in files) {

  # read the file, specify the correct separator
  data <- read.table(file, sep = "|")

  # set the column names
  names(data) <- c("date", "level")

  # define the output file name: the file should be written to
  # out_path and have the same name as the original file
  outfile <- file.path(out_path, basename(file))

  # write the file. You need to specify the separator (|), and
  # omit row names and quotes
  write.table(data, outfile, sep = "|", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
}
```

The example file from your question will be turned into:

```
date|level
09/21/1299 |23
09/22/1999 |25
09/23/1999 |25
```

Note that the headers are not nicely aligned. If the files are read as csv files, this should not be a problem.